# How do you exclude a folder from build in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio

I have an example project from a vendor, and in the instructions, I'm told to right-click a folder in the Solution and select "exclude from build." But there's no such feature in VS 2015, and I can't find an equivalent online.

I've tried to just remove the folders from the project, and I expected that to work, but then I get compilation errors, so I suspect there are some dependencies that don't allow that solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should see an option for `Exclude from Project`, when you `right click` a folder in solution explorer. Following screenshot displays this.

[image]

Comment: Hi Agalo, I don't see the same when I right click a folder in the solution explorer. But unlike your screenshot, each folder in the solution explorer also has a "T" in the lower left corner. I imagine that might have something to do with it...

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2015 do you have? Can you also post a screenshot, when you right click on a folder.